# Problem connecting to SQL Server RDS from Laravel in EC2 Server

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

When doing tests such as php artisan migrate I get the following error:

> Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\Error\FatalError
> Unsupported processor architecture.

I added all the data to `.env` and that is the error I get.

Comment: Do you get any errors when you do `composer install`?

Comment: Laravel is installed and works fine. The error comes whenever I try to access the database

Comment: See here http://44.202.14.7

Comment: Please share your environment details (OS and PHP versions). If I'm to guess, this is related to SQL Server driver.

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 php 8.1 before this I was having a diver error but after install this is what I get

Comment: Hi @sykez you may be right. After doing the steps here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15 I am getting in Ubuntu E: Unable to locate package mssql-tools18 and E: Unable to locate package msodbcsql18

Comment: Hmm. The error from your app is coming from `sqlsrv_connect()` so it's definitely related to it. Looks like you don't have the repo setup yet. Did you execute the script provided in the [guide](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15#ubuntu18)? Best thing to do right now is to reinstall the ODBC driver and SQL Server PHP driver again. But keep in mind about the versions/compatibility. Also, what's your SQL Server version, and the output of these commands: `apt show msodbcsql*` and `pecl list`?

Comment: @sykez yes the problem seems to be the packages are not installing from that guide take a look.

sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y msodbcsql18
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package msodbcsql18
sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y mssql-tools18
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package mssql-tools18

I tried doing the guid on a new instance and I get the same error

Comment: It still doesn't sound like the repo was setup. Try running this first: `curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/20.04/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list`, and then try again.

Comment: @sykez I removed the old file and run the curl command. New file was created with ```deb [arch=amd64,armhf,arm64] https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/20.04/prod focal main``` but it still has the same issue of not locating package

Comment: Alright. You'll probably need to update the packages list. Run these commands: `curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -` and `apt-get update`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243568/discussion-between-carlos-castillo-and-sykez).